# What does くるりと回れば means? Is this some kind of expression?

Tags: translation, sentence

[image]

The old woman is recalling what her daughter said before leaving the village. I understand

> 中の者も　外の者も関係ない

"Whatever it's a person from inside the village or outside it doesn't matter"

> 神楽や歌にはその力がある

"Such power exists inside the kagura and the dance."

However what I'm stumbled is the middle sentence

> くるりと回れば　1つになる

"1つになる" may be modifying 神楽 and 歌 but I'm not convinced. Likely it may say that the people outside and inside became one under that power.

However, I'm stumbled of the meaning of くるりと回れば

Either she's talking about the dance she performs, or it's "after seeing the world" or some nuance I'm missing.

She should be saying that the Kagura and the dance don't discriminate and they have the power to unify  people.

Comment: It's just [turn](https://youtu.be/xg_nXRHoqkE). Unless it's about some sort of magic dance that forcibly enchants people, it's probably about how dancing together creates a sense of solidarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

くるりと回る here probably describes certain motion in kagura and thus figuratively refers to performing kagura. I’m not sure who performs kagura, but the subject of一つになる is both 中の者 and 外の者. Therefore, the entire sentence means “if someone performs kagura, both groups of people (villagers and strangers) become unified.”

My guess is kagura performers are also 中の者 and 外の者, and then it have nuance of ”getting along with each other through performing kagura together.”

Comment: She's the one who performs it, for context.

Comment: Oh, just disregard my guess. Then the sentence implies the villagers an strangers getting along with each other just watching her performing kagura… It sound a little bit strange to me, but it is probably a “power” of the performance as she said.